# Which Format of Images are supported by OpenCV

Tags: opencv

For a project of mine a require an image(logo of some company) to be overlaid on the main screen and I want only the Logo to be visible not the borders or the extra regions of the image, I even tried overlaying the .png image but then also the borders are visible in black color along with the logo.

Can anyone let me know which format of the image shall I use So that only the logo of my image gets displayed not the extra part which lies in the rectangular part of the image.

If u need more clarification... Please let me know

Thanks :)

Comment: Does your image have transparency?

Comment: PNG should be suitable. Are you sure the parts of the image outside the logo are fully transparent? Most image processing applications have (or can set) checkered background that should show through those parts of the image.

Comment: I'll have my input video through a normal webcam which after a little processing I'll be displaying on the output Window with a small Logo of the Client Company. Now the Logo that I was using was a .png image and only the logo shape was visible rest was ntot visible but when I overlaid the image over my video output it is showing black borders around the logo (i.e in the remaining rectangular region of the logo). Hope this makes it clear for you.

Comment: It isn't clear. Can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like what you should do is crop your image using an image editing program, like Paint, [Paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net), [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or Photoshop, and then display or overlay the cropped image.

If you really want to use OpenCV to do this, here's [how to load and display images](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html), and here's the [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) function's documentation. From the latter, to answer your question's title:

> Currently, the following file formats are supported:
>
> ```
>     Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
>     JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see the Notes section)
>     JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the Notes section)
>     Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the Notes section)
>     Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm (always supported)
>     Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
>     TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see the Notes section)
> ```