# header information is missing from image, after writing using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tiff, qgis

I am doing complement of an image using open-cv python, while writing the image, open-cv is not writing the header information in the complemented image. my image data are in TIFF format.

i am doing like this...

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.tiff", -1)
for i in xrange(0, len(img)):
     for j in xrange(0, len(i)):
          img[i][j] = 65535-img[i][j]
cv2.imwrite("complemented.tif", img)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335308/can-i-load-a-multi-frame-tiff-through-opencv

Comment: opencv supports tiff, http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread

Comment: see this also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854343/which-format-of-images-are-supported-by-opencv

Comment: What header info would you like to see?  Do you have information in the original image that you want preserved?

Comment: yes, i have information of header in the original image. and i want the same header info to be attached with complemented image.

Answer (score 0):

As described in this [link](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm), `Each TIFF file begins with a image file header which points to one or more image file directories, which contain the image data and image information.`, header information is required for multi-image TIFF.

Multi-image TIFF is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335308/can-i-load-a-multi-frame-tiff-through-opencv) in OpenCV as @Haris mentioned in the comments.

Since, multi-image TIFF is not supported, it is most likely that header information is not read using `imread` and thus cannot be written using `imwrite`.

Comment: Then what are the other options ??. I want to do the complement a .tif image file.